# Keeping notifications in the bar after restarting the phone

Tags: android

Is it possible to keep notification after rebooting the phone? I mean, I added some notifications and they are in status bar, but after reboot they disappear.

Comment: What do you mean "I added some notifications"?  Are you writing an app?  If so, your app will need to start on boot and determine if it needs to create the notifications again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. All status bar notifications are removed when the phone is rebooted.

If you need to preserve the notifications then you should implement a BOOT_COMPLETED listener and re-create the notifications from your original data source.